# Own replicateM implementation

Tags: haskell

I wonder if it is possible to write own **replicateM** implementation for ***Bool***
values without importing Monad module? It does look quite complicated when I looked into Haskell source code, but I would like to know how does that function work and how should it look like.

Comment: `Bool` aren't monads, so you can just use `replicate`.

Comment: But `replicateM 2 [True,False]` is not returning the same stuff as `replicate 2 [True, False]`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem statement yet. Can you state clearly why having a "complicated" implementation is a problem for you, and by what criteria we can consider ourselves to have provided an alternate implementation that is less "complicated" enough that we have solved your problem?

Comment: It's simple - I just want to know how does it work and since I don't clearly know what's going on in `replicateM`, I'd be very happy to see how it should be implemented. I'm sure that will help me understand the whole process.

Comment: @user2342783 re: "happy to see how it should be implemented"; the implementation in full is available [on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#replicateM). It depends on just a few other functions whose source are also available on Hackage. So I suspect you want something more than just "how it should be implemented" -- but I don't know what.

Comment: I think you are wrong :) I don't want you to write code for me - I just don't know **HOW** does that function work...

Comment: I think what you're actually having trouble grasping is the list monad. Because `replicateM 2 [True, False]` is working in the list monad. That the lists contain `Bool`s is really irrelevant here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `replicateM` is:

```
replicateM n x = sequence (replicate n x)
```

and `replicate` has type `Int -> a -> [a]`, so for example `replicate 4 True` is `[True, True, True, True]`.

For a list argument `l = [True, False]`, `replicate 2 l` is `[[True, False], [True, False]]`. Your comment asks what the different is between `replicate` and `replicateM`, and you can see that `replicateM` uses `replicate` but then calls `sequence` on the result.

The type of `sequence` is:

```
Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

In this example, `m` is list, so it transforms a list of lists into another list of lists.
As you point out, the result is different from calling `replicate 2 l`. The definition for `sequence` is:

```
sequence ms = foldr k (return []) ms
            where
              k m m' = do { x <- m; xs <- m'; return (x:xs) }
```

The `do` block for lists works like the following list comprehension:

```
[[x:xs] | x <- m, xs <- m']
```

which is a cartesian product, i.e. a new list is formed by consing each element of `m` in front of each list in the accumulator.

One way to think of lists is modelling non-deterministic choice, so the result is all possible outcomes of `n` choices from the input list.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not pretending to answer the question but lack of formatting in comment is forcing me to.
Brief version is `replicateM n m` is equivalent for

```
m >>= (\x1 -> m >>= (\x2 -> ... m >>= ( \xn -> return [x1,x2,...,xn])..))
```

or similar

```
do 
  x1 <- m
  x2 <- m
  ...
  xn <- m
  return [x1,x2,...,xn]
```

So for list `replicateM` returning cartesian product of `n` equal lists. For `Maybe` it will be list of length `n` or `Nothing`. For "action performing" monad it will be result of `n` actions performed, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One way to implement `replicateM` would be:

```
replicateM n = sequence . replicate n
```

Does this help your understanding? Of course, the tricky part lies in the operation of `sequence` which has the following interesting type:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

Hence,

```
replicateM 3 (Just 1) 
  = sequence (replicate 3 (Just 1))
  = sequence ([Just 1, Just 1, Just 1])
  = Just [1,1,1]
```

Comment: > "Of course, the tricky part lies in the operation of sequence which has the following interesting type"

I beleive this function isn't that tricky either: it's just something like foldr1 >>